# Добавление пагинации к слайдеру на swiper 6.8.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, swiper, carousel

В приложении на React делаю карусель с использованием "swiper": "6.8.4"
Не добавляется пагинация ни в каком виде.
Может быть вы увидете в чем ошибка? Спасибо

[swiper pagination api docs](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#pagination)

```
...
function Carousel() {
  return (
      <Swiper
        
        modules={[EffectFade, Keyboard, Pagination, Autoplay]}
        pagination={{
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          type: 'bullets',
        }}

        effect={'fade'}
        fadeEffect={{crossFade: true}}
        freeMode={true}
        autoplay={{
          delay: 2500,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        }}
        keyboard={{
          enabled: true,
          onlyInViewport: true,
          onPageUp: true,
        }}
        className="mySwiper"
        cssMode={true}
        loop={false}
        mousewheel={true}
        slidesPerView={1}
      >
        <SwiperSlide>0</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>1</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
  )
}

export default Carousel
```

Comment: Смотрели этот пример из документации https://swiperjs.com/demos#pagination? Там есть кнопка [React](https://swiperjs.com/demos#) если хотите смотреть на исходный код. Попробуйте сравнить то что там и то что у вас в простом варианте, а потом по одному добавляйте настройки

Comment: Забыл сказать, когда перейдёте к коду на React, то там будет последняя версия, но слева будет переключатель версии, можете там выбрать то что вам нужно ну или в самом `package.json` указать нужную вам версию